# GAE import error

Tags: html, google-app-engine, pythonpath

I am trying to use this python module [HTML.py](http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html) but GAE gives me  `ImportError: No module named HTML`

According to IDLE path browser the path is here:

```
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\HTML.py
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: How did you try to import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put HTML.py in your applications root directory, where app.yaml is at. It should work, assuming HTML.py does not use any non-whitelisted modules.

You should use [Python 2.5](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/).  It will probably save you from some future headaches.  I think this is also mentioned in the App Engine Python [Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html).

Comment: Great! Thank you. I had to put the HTML.py into the app folder; as you said; putting the folder HTML did not work. (I have mako folder and that works) I have Python 2.6.1. Thanks again.